# Is there a way to recover Google Cloud Function source code when the bucket does not exist, but it can still run?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-container-registry

I have 13 Google Cloud Functions running in my Google Cloud Project. Several of them are triggered by Google Cloud Scheduler. I went to make an edit to one of the functions the other day and got the following error when trying to view the "SOURCE".

[image]

When looking into this issue, the culprit seems to be that the Archive Bucket has been deleted or that the name has changed. When looking through the Container Registry as well as the buckets, I can confirm that they are no longer there. I think another developer in the project may have accidentally deleted them when cleaning up images from an old project.

That being said, when looking at the logs I have noticed that the functions being triggered by Google Cloud Scheduler are still successfully running on their schedules even though I can no longer access the source code. The functions are logging data the I console within the source code even though it is no longer there.

My question is whether or not these are recoverable and what it would take to find them.

I have tried looking for the images and the buckets to see if they were renamed and I could not find them. I also created a new function in the same region and it spun up a new image and bucket, but it did not contain any reference to the other missing functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the source code of a Google Cloud Function if the bucket that contained the code has been deleted. The source code is stored in the bucket, so if the bucket is deleted, the code is also deleted. If the function is still running, it is because the code has been deployed and is being run from a different location. You can view the logs for the function to see what code is being executed, but you will not be able to retrieve the original source code.

If you need to access the source code for the function, you will need to redeploy the code to a new bucket. You can do this by creating a new bucket and uploading the code, or by using the Cloud Functions API or the gcloud command-line tool to deploy the code to the new bucket.